# Is it possible to import a common class outside the folder in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm struggling to understand how the import statements are resolving the paths and am unable to determine why this is failing. What I have is an Angular component which is importing a class in a different folder. It looks like this:

[image]

My component references that common class like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { State } from '../common/models/state';

@Component({
    selector: 'apartment'
})
export class ApartmentComponent {
    states: State[];
}
```

I can get my module, component and related classes to load. However this common class just won't load. I get this error in the Chrome dev console:

```
Apartments:260 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/DemoApp/scripts/components/common/models/state
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost/DemoApp/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:647:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/DemoApp/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost/DemoApp/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost/DemoApp/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:33)
Error loading http://localhost/DemoApp/scripts/components/common/models/state as "../common/models/state" from http://localhost/DemoApp/scripts/components/apartment/apartment.component.js
```

**Is it possible to load from an outside directory via a relative path?** I played around with systemjs.config.js to get this far, but I feel like there's something I must be missing for why this import isn't working.

Note that I have tsconfig.json using these settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules_dep",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

and system.config.js is adding extra packages via these means:

```
/**
* System configuration for Angular 2 samples
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
*/
(function(global, window) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs/'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };

    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'forms'
    ];

    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        };
    }

    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = {
            main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        };

        map['@angular/' + pkgName] = 'npm:@angular/' + pkgName + '/';
    }

    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

    //Adding Additional Packages
    $.each(commonPackageNames, function (index, pkgName) {
        console.log("Loading (" + pkgName.name + ") from '" + pkgName.path + "'");
        var sName = pkgName.name;

        packages[sName] = {
            main: pkgName.main,
            defaultExtension: pkgName.defaultExtension
        }

        map[sName] = pkgName.path;
    });

    var config = {
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': window.baseURL + '/node_modules/'
        },
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    System.config(config);
})(this, window);
```

We separate modules per page, so they are configured via a apartment.config.js that looks like this:

```
(map = map || {}).app = 'apartmentmodule';

commonPackageNames.push({
    name: 'apartmentmodule',
    main: 'main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    path: window.baseURL + 'scripts/components/apartmentmodule'
});
```

Comment: It is definitely possible to move around in your app's structure and pull from other folders.

app
../component1
../component2/subfolder/

If you were in subfolder you would do "../../component1/component1";

I would also make sure your `<base href=></base>` is set properly as it determines the start point for your paths.

Comment: Try using second answer of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547364/angular-2-imports-between-different-folders and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538205/import-a-shared-service-that-lives-outside-the-app-folder-in-an-angular-2-app-in

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you exported your `State` class in `state.ts`? Like this:

```
export class State {

}
```

Your imports seems alright, this is the first mistake I thought of. Another one is that you didn't compile some of your files, including `state.ts` to `.js`. Check if there's corresponding `state.js` and `state.js.map` files in your `~/common/models` folder.

Comment: I double checked, it is generating the *.js and *.map.js files. Also State is properly exporting.

Comment: I noticed that the path that it's complaining about is correct if I append a file type to it. Any ideas on why it might not specify .js while loading?

Comment: @MatthewRhoden I really don't, sorry, wish I could be of more help. I'll delete my answer when you see this, hope someone with more experience can help you.

Answer (score 0):

use import { State } from '../../common/models/state';